# Is it possible to integrate third party applications in JSF?

Tags: php, jsf, jsf-2, web

I have a third party chat application developed in php. So, if I want to integrate that application in my JSF application, will it work? i.e. one part of a web page will be handled by JSF & another part which is chat application, will be handled by php.

Mixing up two technologies isn't a good idea.But still, if it's possible,then how can it be done?

Alternative suggestions are most welcome apart from developing the chat application in JSF from ground up [which I may have to if there's no choice].

Comment: any search efforts done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not specifically "Third party applicaitions", but specifically "PHP", yes you can run PHP code on a Java EE container. There are so far 2 libraries available which enable reading/parsing/executing PHP code on a Java EE container: [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and [JSR223 + PHP-bridge](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/entry/native_php_in_glassfish_with).

An alternative is to install [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org) in front of the Java EE container. This is in real production world also often done in order to have a "100% uptime" proxy in front of a Java EE container so that it's among others possible to show a "Sorry, this site is down for maintenance, come back in a few minutes" maintenance screen when the Java EE container is brought down for a redeploy, or even advanced loadbalancing tasks when there's a cluster of containers. You could effortlessly run PHP over there.

Whatever way you choose to get PHP to run along with Java EE, to embed it in a JSF web application, use a HTML `<iframe>` element pointing to the URL of the PHP application. To share some session data, make sure that it's listening on the same domain, so that you can share cookies. Having it on the same domain would also enable JavaScript to interact between the iframe content and the parent page, if necessary.

On the other hand, developing a chat application in JSF2 from ground up isn't that hard though if you use the right libraries. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) has even a "homegrown" chat application example on its [`<p:push>` showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf). It is perhaps not "advanced", but it's a decent kickoff example.

Comment: I've already checked PrimeFaces chat demo.But I was wondering whether it's possible to dynamically generate chat window for each user[as in facebook chat] by JSF or primeface? A little heads up would be great.

Comment: If the user is already logged-in (like as in Facebook) just add the user directly to chat group instead of asking the user to login. Or, if you want a public chat, just autogenerate the username like `Guest123`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.It really helped me to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can host that applicaton and include that application into the new application page using `<IFrame/>` tag

```
<iframe src="urlToYourChatApplicaton"></iframe>
```